# MySql auto TIME_STAMP not working

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have created a table where I have set a column, `payment_time`, to `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` while creating a table.

When I insert values I set `payment_time` to blank with `''`. However, when I checked the table on the payment_time is showing 0000-00-00 00:00:00 where I am looking for the current time. Am I making a mistake here?

Comment: we need examples of inputs you specify and probably a DESCRIBE tablename

Comment: add it to the question please.  i/someone can format it for you

Comment: Please append it to your original question, not as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
     payment_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and modify your insert statment like that

```
    INSERT INTO TB (`payment_time`) VALUES ('NOW()' ); 
--dont specifie the id column  it will be automatically inserted
```

EDIT.

```
 INSERT INTO TB (`col1`, `col2`,`payment_time`) VALUES ('somevalue1','somevalue2','NOW()' ); 
 -- dont use the id column just the other columns , and be sure that columns are in right ORDER
```

due to your edited question here is solution

```
INSERT INTO donors (firstName,lastName,gender,email,amount,currency)VALUES(  'MD.Borhan', 'Safa', 'm', 'borhansafa@yahoo.com', '5', 'GBP' );
```

Comment: it is saying...#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: It is working now but when I have added some more column and tried the  above insert it is saying the error which i have mentioned previously

Comment: dont insert the value of `ID` column , just insert other values without `ID`

Comment: you have to match up your NOW() with the correct column name INSERT INTO TB (`payment_time`,'col2','col3','col4') VALUES ('NOW()','val2','val3','val4' );

Answer (score 0):

```
payment_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Use this and then do not use `payment_time` in the insert statement. Current date will be automatically allocated to your respective entry.